# How does Datetime.timestamp works?

Tags: python, datetime, operating-system, timestamp, strptime

Hey Guys I have got a code which should compare the timestamps of my image files now I have got following code:

```html
from datetime import datetime
import os

def gettime(folder_dir):
    time_stamps = []
    for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
        if images.endswith(".jpg"):
            fn, fext = os.path.splitext(images)

            # string name
            timestamp1 = fn

            # Convert String to datetime Object
            t1 = datetime.strptime(timestamp1, "%H_%M_%S")
            t1 = datetime.timestamp(t1)

            # check if imgs have been taken in similar time (the seconds you want +1)
            if len(time_stamps) == 0 or abs(int(t1) - min(time_stamps)) >= 11 or abs(int(t1) - max(time_stamps)) >= 11:
                time_stamps.append(int(t1))
            else:
                os.remove(os.path.join(folder_dir, images))

gettime("Bilder")
```

If I execute it I code following values from the timestamp in the array, now I want to know rather, how I can change the value of 1900-01-01 09:02:05 to only 09:02:05 or I want to know how the value -2208956275 is generated from 1900-01-01 09:02:05
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get string with only time from your Datetime object you can do something like this:

```
datetime.strftime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Timestamp is displayed as large negative number because it's in POSIX format which is seconds passed since 1970.01.01.